# Scheduling cron Linux

Tags: linux, cron

I would like to schedule a cron to take backup of my database every three days at mid-night.

So, is this correct?

```
0 0 */3 * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -hhost_ip -uusername my_db_name -ppassword > my_backup.sql
```

This question might have asked earlier, but I just want to confirm this.
Thanks. Any help would be of immense help!

Comment: You are good. 1) Ensure that the commands runs ok from prompt. 2) my_backup.sql is being overwritten is that desired?

Comment: " I just want to confirm, since I am going to place this cron in production site." - you should have already confirmed that on your test server; you should also have checked that you can restore the generated backup.

Comment: @vimalnath: not testing backup-related things is a capital sin. You should not even be considering pushing something on production that you haven't tested elsewhere.

Comment: @Mat ok thanks will first test it on my staging server.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no.
you miss user

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
```

Comment: am already logged in as root user.
so, I do not think it is required.
Correct me , if wrong.

Comment: @vimalnath in /etc/crontab need user. in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/user(or alternative)  don't need